# how to redirect to another page with vue component template

Tags: html, vue.js, laravel-5, vue-component

I want to redirect template component. I go to another template component but I don't find the way

```
      <template>
        <div class="section-wrapper mg-t-20">
            <label class="section-title">Gestion De Datos</label>
            <!-- <p class="mg-b-20 mg-sm-b-40">Below is an example of a pill navigation in both light and dark.</p> -->
            <div class="pd-10 bd">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column flex-md-row" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#" role="tab">Reporte</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item" >
                  <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="REDIRECT TO ANOTHER VUE COMPONENT PAGE" role="tab">Agregar Cliente</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#" role="tab">Asignar</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#" role="tab">Cambiar Estado</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#" role="tab">Importar</a></li>
                <!-- <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#" role="tab">Contact</a></li> -->
                </ul>
            </div><!-- pd-10 -->
        </div><!-- section-Datos -->
      </template>
```

[Image of source code vue.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ps2VR.png)

Comment: [Vue Router](https://router.vuejs.org/) is what you are looking for....

Comment: how i can do that with vue router?